# Error in dividing the column values into Top 20% and Bottom 80%

Tags: r

I have a vector such that:

```
Vec <- data.frame( Vec = c("70.0600", "8.5100", "5.8600", "399.9800", "9.0600", "78.8200", "71.4600") )
```

And I want to divide the above values into Top 20% and Bottom 80% in a way such that the result should look like:

```
 Vec        Dec
 70.0600    Top_20
 .          .
 .          .
 5.8600     Bottom_80
```

I am trying with something like that:

```
Vec$Quartile <- quantile(Vec$Vec, probs = c(0.20, 0.80))
```

But I got exactly 50-50% values of data:

```
 sum( Vec$Quartile>20 )
```

I am not sure where I was wrong?

Comment: Based on the data you provided `Vec` value of `70.06` will be `Bottom_80`.

Comment: @AntoniosK thank you for this info. may be you are correct. but let's consider a scenario where these values are sales from a store, then highest revenues will fall into top 20 and the rest will fall into bottom 80. Of course this is just a hypothetical scenario but something like that might be possible. right?

Comment: For any set on numerical values the highest will fall into top 20 and the rest into bottom 80. What I'm saying is that you could have posted an expected result that matches the data you provided :)

Comment: @AntoniosK sure, thank you :) this is really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)

Vec <- data.frame(Vec = c(70.0600, 8.5100, 5.8600, 399.9800, 9.0600, 78.8200, 71.4600))

Vec %>%
  mutate(up = quantile(Vec, .8),
         part = ifelse(Vec > up, "Top_20", "Bottom_80"))

     Vec     up      part
1  70.06 77.348 Bottom_80
2   8.51 77.348 Bottom_80
3   5.86 77.348 Bottom_80
4 399.98 77.348    Top_20
5   9.06 77.348 Bottom_80
6  78.82 77.348    Top_20
7  71.46 77.348 Bottom_80
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple approach without loading additional libraries:

#### Result

```
   value       dec
1 399.98    Top_20
2  78.82    Top_20
3  70.06 Bottom_20
4   8.51 Bottom_20
5   5.86 Bottom_20
6   9.06 Bottom_20
7  71.46 Bottom_20
```

#### Code

```
Vec <- c(70.0600, 8.5100, 5.8600, 399.9800, 9.0600, 78.8200, 71.4600)

q <- quantile(Vec, .8)

Vec <- rbind(
    data.frame(value = subset(Vec, Vec > q), dec = "Top_20"),
    data.frame(value = subset(Vec, Vec <= q), dec = "Bottom_20"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Surely this is awesome as it doesn't use any package, but base functions.

Comment: You could also use `Vec[order(-Vec[, 1]), ]` to order it by descending value.